# Debugging Class Function Implementation C++

Tags: c++, function, class

I could use some expertise in debugging my code if someone would kindly help. I'm trying to call a function from a class file and I'm running into a few errors. I'm in the process of learning c++. My errors are below:

```
In function 'int main()':    
error: no matching function for call to 'MyPoint::distance(MyPoint&)'
note: candidate is:
note: double MyPoint::distance(double)
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "MyPoint.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyPoint point1;
    MyPoint point2(10.2, 34.8);
    cout << point1.distance(point2);
    return 0;
}
```

MyPoint.h

```
#ifndef MYPOINT_H
#define MYPOINT_H
using namespace std;
class MyPoint
{
    public:
        MyPoint();
        MyPoint(double, double);
        double getX();
        double getY();
        double distance(double);
    private:
        double x, y;
};
#endif // MYPOINT_H
```

MyPoint.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "MyPoint.h"
using namespace std;
MyPoint::MyPoint()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

MyPoint::MyPoint(double x1, double y1)
{
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
}

double MyPoint::getX()
{
    return x;
}

double MyPoint::getY()
{
    return y;
}

double MyPoint::distance(double p2)
{
    return sqrt((x - p2.x) * (x - p2.x) + (y - p2.y) * (y - p2.y));
}
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `distance` as this:

```
double distance(double);
```

Which means the `MyPoint::distance` method expects a `double`, not another `MyPoint`.  It looks like you can just change the delcaration and it might work.

In your header:

```
double distance(MyPoint&);
```

and your implementation:

```
double MyPoint::distance(MyPoint& p2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `double MyPoint::distance(double p2)` is a wrong definition. It should receive `MyPoint` instead of `double`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change distance method in your MyPoint class:

declare in .h

```
double distance(const MyPoint& p2);
```

implement in .cpp

```
double MyPoint::distance(const MyPoint& p2)
{
    return sqrt((x - p2.x) * (x - p2.x) + (y - p2.y) * (y - p2.y));
}
```